# ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key for persian name and domain website

Tags: recaptcha

[image]

I applied all the settings in the image on the website, set the site key and security code. But unfortunately, it runs the following:

```
ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key for english name and domain website
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar issue. My resolution was to delete the key that was not working and got a new key for my domain. And this now works with all my sub-domains as well without having to explicitly specify them in the recaptcha admin area.